# Getting " Failed to communicate with proxy " from weblogic

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

I am trying to connect to server using proxy via weblogic and I am getting response successfully but after response below error keep getting generated after every 5 minute.

```
   <Jul 9, 2022 12:05:17 AM UTC> <Error> <Net> <BEA-000903> <Failed to communicate with proxy: proxy.conexus.svc.local/3128. Will try connection /443 now.
java.net.ProtocolException: Unrecognized response from SSL proxy: 'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request'
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.makeConnectionUsingProxy(HttpsClient.java:494)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.openServer(HttpsClient.java:353)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:565)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:546)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:235)
```

Can anyone help me to get through this issue, It will be a great help as I am stucked with this error.

wlfullclient dependency

```
<groupId>csi-third-party-components.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>wlfullclient</artifactId>
```

Thanks,
Anshu

Comment: Seems like your proxy URL unreachable or invalid.

Comment: @user:6316044 Can you help here please ?